# How to configure Firewalld to block incoming traffic on loopback interface?

Tags: centos, rhel, iptables, firewalld

I have firewalld enabled and configured as below:

```
loopback (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: lo
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" source address="127.0.0.0/8" port port="8080" protocol="tcp" drop
    rule family="ipv4" destination address="127.0.0.1" port port="8080" protocol="tcp" drop
```

However, running `curl -I localhost:8080` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` instead of blocked.

When firewalld is disabled and iptables is enabled with the rule:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

The request is blocked!

Why is firewalld not working as expected? The configuration is runtime-to-permanent and reloaded.

Comment: Honest question: Is curl using IP4 in this case?

Comment: Yeah it could connect to ::1. Also `-i lo/-o lo -j ACCEPT` could be the default *top* of the list rules, so I've no idea how to override them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It is everything explained in this RH [article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4944201).
Not everyone has RH account, but I wasn't able to find another article.

I changed the original command from the article (to fix the error `--dports` and to match the OP needs).

```
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-passthrough ipv4 -I OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REJECT
```

The RH article says nothing about ipv6, but of course in your case you need to block possibility to reach your `lo` over ipv6 also:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-passthrough ipv6 -I OUTPUT -d ::1/128 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REJECT
```